# How do I change a MySQL query into a Drupal query?

Tags: database

```
mysql_query("SELECT nid,title, type,created, v_api.ContentSum
  FROM `node` n
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT content_id,
                     SUM(CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1
                         WHEN value=0 THEN -1
                         ELSE 0
                     END) AS ContentSum
                FROM votingapi_vote
               WHERE value_type = 'option'
               GROUP BY content_id) v_api
    ON n.nid = v_api.content_id
where type='provider'
ORDER BY v_api.ContentSum DESC, created DESC LIMIT 0 , 22");
```

How do I change this query into a Drupal query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the drupal [Database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/group/database/6). Without thinking about what you want to achieve with your query I would write it like that:

```
db_query_range("SELECT nid, title, type, created, v_api.ContentSum
                FROM {node} n
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT content_id,
                                  SUM(CASE
                                       WHEN value=1 THEN 1
                                       WHEN value=0 THEN -1
                                       ELSE 0
                                      END) AS ContentSum
                           FROM {votingapi_vote}
                           WHERE value_type = 'option'
                           GROUP BY content_id) v_api
                ON n.nid = v_api.content_id
                WHERE type='provider'
                ORDER BY v_api.ContentSum DESC, created DESC", 0, 22)
```

Maybe one of the values (type,value_type,...) could be set via arguments, too.

EDIT:

here again with arguments:

```
db_query_range("SELECT nid, title, type, created, v_api.ContentSum
                FROM {node} n
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT content_id,
                                  SUM(CASE
                                       WHEN value=1 THEN 1
                                       WHEN value=0 THEN -1
                                       ELSE 0
                                      END) AS ContentSum
                           FROM {votingapi_vote}
                           WHERE value_type = %s
                           GROUP BY content_id) v_api
                ON n.nid = v_api.content_id
                WHERE type= %s
                ORDER BY v_api.ContentSum DESC, created DESC", 'option', 'provider', 0, 22)
```

Comment: thank you, if i want to use the replace character to in place of the option and provider. how to alter the code?

Comment: Basically, in the query, you'd replace `option` and `provider` with `%s`, then add two more parameters to the function call. See the [documentation on the db_query() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6) to see how to use placeholders in SQL queries.

Comment: but i don't know how to add them.when i add like this, it shows an error.WHERE value_type = '%s' GROUP BY content_id,'%s')  WHERE type='%s'
                ORDER BY v_api.ContentSum DESC, created DESC",'provider', 0, 22)

Comment: when i used the with arguments code, it's can't work. but used the above is ok. why?

Comment: What is the error, exactly?

Comment: Oh, I noted that nonsenz edited their post to add the function call with the arguments, but the arguments were in the wrong order. I edited the post; the changes should show up soon.

Comment: oh, yep you're right. sorry about that and thx.